# Hide a block in drupal if an li tag has text using jquery

Tags: jquery, drupal

I want to hide a block if  `<li class="first last">` has the text 120V in it.

This is the code i wrote but the block is still showing.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   // check to see if the li tag with css classes .first .last has the text 120V in it 

   if ($(".first .last").text() == "120V"){

   //if true hide the sidebar-second
       $("#my-block").hide();
    }
   else {
   //if false show the sidebar second
        $("#my-block").show();
    }       

    });
});
```

Where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
$(".first.last").text()
```

instead of:

```
$(".first .last").text()
```

You don't need any space here since space indicate the descendant elements. So your current selector will select any descendant with class `last` inside any element with class `first`.

Comment: Seem like you've an extra closing `});` at the end. Remove it and try again.